# Powershell Send an email if success or if error

Tags: powershell

I have a script that looks at a CSV, filters the email address and performs some tasks:

```
foreach($aduser in (import-csv "C:\Temp\users.csv")){                 
Get-ADUser -filter "emailaddress -eq '$($aduser.emailaddress)'"|
Set-ADobject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

Get-ADUser -filter "emailaddress -eq '$($aduser.emailaddress)'" | 
Set-ADUser -Enabled $false

Get-ADUser -filter "emailaddress -eq '$($aduser.emailaddress)'" |Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Sep 20,OU=Disabled User Accounts,DC=Mydomain,DC=Domain,DC=uk" -PassThru | Disable-ADAccout}

If ($Error){
    
    $FailMailParams = @{
        To = 'Example@Gmail.com'
        From = 'Example@Gmail.com'
        SmtpServer = 'My.smtp.server'
        Subject = 'Script Errors Out'
        Body = 'There was an error with the script!!'
        }

    Send-MailMessage @FailMailParams
    
    
    } else {
         $SuccessMailParams = @{
        To = 'Example@Gmail.com'
        From = 'Example@gmail.com'
        SmtpServer = 'My.smtp.server'
        Subject = 'Success'
        Body = 'The script ran successfully'
        }

         Send-MailMessage @SuccessMailParams
       }
```

The problem I am facing is that even if the script runs successfully I still get the error email. If I change the code to `if ($error -eq 1)` and the code errors out I get the successful email. I think it's the `If ($error)` Variable causing the issue but I don't know what to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error control can be handled in different ways. In your code, you have nothing that is indicating **$error** that should be set to 1.

I suggest you to find some examples of how to use the **Try-Catch** structure, as you will have to use it a lot in Powershell.

Find an example below which should be easy to adopt for your already made code:

```
try
{
    # Code that performs the work intended
}
catch
{
    # What to do in case any error is raised from above Try section
    $error = 1
}
finally
{
    # Here you post code that will be executed no matter errors happened or not, 
    # for example your email definition and execution.
}
```

Said this, your code has more room for improvement, but if you are starting with it, let's not focus on that part still.

Comment: thank you for the reply so if I was to do something along the lines of: `Finally{ 

If ($Error = 1){

$FailMailParams = @{` would that be the correct method?

Comment: Yes, that would work. As next-bit to improve the code, I can suggest you create only one mailparams variable, filled with the success values inside the try block. Inside the catch, you re-assign values for the same mailparams variable with the failed ones (they will be overwritten only in case of error. In the finally block, you can just add the send mail command. Let me know how it goes and please mark answer as correct it it resolved your question, I am a new contributor in the community :)